# Show that $\frac{hr}{R^2 \sin B}(\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\sin^2B) - \sin^2B - \frac{1}{R}\sqrt{\frac{hr}{\sin B}}(2\cos\phi\cos B\sin B) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having a hard time showing that the left-hand side of the following equation does indeed equal zero.

$$\frac{hr}{R^2 \sin B}(\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\sin^2B) - \sin^2B - \frac{1}{R}\sqrt{\frac{hr}{\sin B}}(2\cos\phi\cos B\sin B) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because it is not true. Take $\phi = 0$, $B=\pi /2$, $h=r=2$ and $R=1$ then the LHS $=3$